# Flutter BLoC 'Future<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, bloc

currently I'm trying to fetch data from API in BLoC pattern. But after the call, it's throwing this message. 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Here is the relevanted codes.

Bloc

```
Stream<NewsState> mapEventToState(NewsEvent event) async* {
    if (event is FetchNews) {
      yield event.isFeatured == true
          ? NewsFeaturedLoading()
          : NewsCommonLoading();

      try {
        print("http req->" + event.isFeatured.toString());
        final List<News> newsList =
            await _fetchNews(event.isFeatured, userRepository.getToken());

        yield event.isFeatured == true
            ? NewsFeaturedSuccess(newsList: newsList)
            : NewsCommonSuccess(newsList: newsList);
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);
        yield event.isFeatured == true
            ? NewsFeaturedFailure(error: error.toString())
            : NewsCommonFailure(error: error.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HttpCall

```
Future<List<News>> _fetchNews(isFeatured, accessToken) async {
  print("before httprequest->>" + accessToken);
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(Constant.baseUrl + "/api/news"),
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "x-access-token": "Bearer " + accessToken,
    },
    body: {
      "isFeatured": isFeatured,
    },
  );

  print("response->>>>" + response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("news-> " + response.body);
    var obj = json.decode(response.body);
    final data = obj["data"] as List;
    return data.map((rawPost) {
      return News(
        id: rawPost['_id'],
        title: rawPost['Title'],
        content: rawPost['Description'],
      );
    }).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception(json.decode(response.body));
  }
}
```

View

```
SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 19.0),
                      child: Text("Common news",
                          style: Constant.newsCommonTextStyle),
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (state is NewsCommonLoading) CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  if (state is NewsCommonSuccess) CommonNews(),
                  if (state is NewsCommonFailure)
                    Text(state.error, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Where does this exception come from? And how can I prevent from this kind of exception? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you update the question to guide me to the area where exactly this error is occurring?

Comment: final List<News> newsList = await _fetchNews(event.isFeatured, userRepository.getToken()); at this line, throwing exception.

Comment: Is userRepository.getToken() an async function?

Comment: yes. it is using async

Comment: @RohanThacker thx man, i figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment `userRepository.getToken()` is an async function so the return value will be Future.

In Dart every function with the `async` keyword will have the return value of `Future<T>`.

To obtain the value of a Future and not the Future itself, two methods are provided.

1. `then()` - Call this function after the async function to get the value.
2. `await` - Add this keyword before and async function to get the value

Update your code to `await userRepository.getToken()` to get the `String` value

Comment: Can I ask one more thing?

Comment: I have one main bloc named as News. I'm trying to trigger two event(FeaturedNews, CommonNews) as parallel, and I added them like "  return NewsBloc(userRepository: userRepository)..add(FetchNews(isFeatured: true)) ..add(FetchNews(isFeatured: false)); ". But only last one is executing. How can I complete first one event too?

Comment: Im sorry i don't use BloC, i dont know how yo solve the issue in your comment

Comment: @ARLEQUINA trigger 1 event as a generic for both FeaturedNews and CommonNews and in the bloc after logic yield 2 states. 1 for FeaturedNews and 2nd for CommonNews.

Comment: I figured it out already. thank you for your help! Sincerely.